# Python parallel library takes longer than sequential execution

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am trying to leverage multi processing by using the Parallel library of python. However strangely I see that the sequential execution is taking longer compared to the parallel version. Below is the code which I am running for comparison

```
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def compute_features(summary, article):
    feature_dict = {}
    feature_dict["f1"] = summary
    feature_dict["f2"] = article
    return feature_dict


def construct_input(n):
    summaries = []
    articles = []
    for i in range(n):
        summaries.append("summary_" + str(i))
        articles.append("articles_" + str(i))
    return summaries, articles


def sequential_test(n):
    print("Sequential test")
    start_time = time.time()
    summaries, articles = construct_input(n)
    feature_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        feature_list.append(compute_features(summaries[i], articles[i]))
    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Total Time Sequential : %s" % total_time)

    # print(feature_list)


def parallel_test(n):
    print("Parallel test")
    start_time = time.time()
    summaries, articles = construct_input(n)
    feature_list = []
    executor = Parallel(n_jobs=8, backend="multiprocessing", prefer="processes", verbose=True)
    # executor = Parallel(n_jobs=4, prefer="threads")
    tasks = (delayed(compute_features)(summaries[i], articles[i]) for i in range(n))
    results = executor(tasks)

    for result in results:
        feature_list.append(result)

    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Total Time Parallel : %s" % total_time)

    # print(feature_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 500000
    sequential_test(n)
    parallel_test(n)
```

I get the following output when I run the code above

```
Sequential test
Total Time Sequential : 1.200118064880371
Parallel test
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Using backend MultiprocessingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done  56 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done 49136 tasks      | elapsed:    1.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done 500000 out of 500000 | elapsed:    4.7s finished
Total Time Parallel : 5.427206039428711
```

I am running this code on a mac with the following configuration

[image]

Can you guys please help me understand why this is so? And if the hardware were to change say to use a GPU would the code be any faster? Appreciate your responses. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It takes some time to start up the processes so that could be why

Comment: What you have here is an example of the overhead. Your tasks are too small and too short. So the overhead of task distribution dominates.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried simulating a computation intensive method from within compute features and it seems to offset the parallelism overhead.